# Why wavelength of Rubidium flame test(red violet) is more than Lithium(crimson red)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, color, periodic-table, light

My teacher show this table from my book
[image]

Here, you can see Red violet wavelength is more than Lithium, which is against order of visible light which increase according to acronym 'VIBGYOR'

According to it violet has lesser wavelength than red(or it's shades)

**what is the basic reason?**

Comment: Look up the Grotrian diagrams for lithium and rubidium and see what the emission-relevant energy levels are. Emission from excited energy levels in atoms is *vastly* more involved than some simple rainbow color ordering. See [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/orbdep.html#c1) for lithium and sodium.

Comment: These types of questions keep coming up. I wish teachers did a better job at explaining these beautiful concepts.

Comment: Realize, also, that there are *many* bright emission lines, and that our perception of the color is the *combination of them*. See https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/rubidiumtable2.htm for a list of Rb lines, and http://www.alexpetty.com/2014/09/21/the-periodic-table-of-light/ for some spectra, including Rb.

Comment: Thank you all, but I am a mere high school (class 11) student I do not know such higher terminology, please can you explain in a easier way (my level) in form of answer, so that I can answer my teacher.

Comment: Excited atoms, of each of the elements you list, can emit multiple colors of light. It happens that rubidium emits some red light, whence how it was named, and it also emits other colors, i.e., 780 nm: this is from the 5p to 5s de-excitation. Look up “rubidium Grotrian diagram”. Then, as @DrMoishePippik said, what you perceive as the emission color is what your eyes and brain interpret the mix of emission colors to be. Even a simple neon bulb produces hundreds of emission lines, despite just looking like a reddish-orange color (to me, anyway).

Comment: Following my own advice (!), check out rubidium’s emission spectrum [here](http://umop.net/spectra/grotrian.php?elem=Rb&) and see the red and violet emission lines. Scroll down as necessary. Also, purple is a mixture of colors whereas violet denotes a range of colors, e.g., 405 nm is violet, as is 419.5 nm, but there is no single wavelength that denotes purple. Same deal with brown.